# How to run.vhd file ( virtual PC image ) in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

How to run a .vhd file (VirtualPC image) in Ubuntu 11.10 and which software can be used to run it?

Answer (score 4):

CONVERT .VHD (VIRTUALPC) FILE TO .VDI (VIRTUALBOX) FORMAT

To do this, I proceeded as follow:

> install qemu package (sudo apt-get install qemu) convert .vhd file:
>
> qemu-img convert -O raw myfile.vhd myfile.bin once the file has been
>
> converted, we convert it to .vdi format using VBoxManage: VBoxManage
>
> convertfromraw myfile.bin myfile.vdi –variant standard
>
> note1: “variant” is specified to ensure we have an expandable vdi file (.bin
>
> file is 17Gb, .vdi file will be only 1.5Gb)
>
> note2: in previous version, “convertfromraw” command was called “convertdd”
> That’s it.

Simply load your vdi file within VirtualBox, do it for all three xp .vhd files and you can now use all these VM more easily.

http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=84

http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=721